# Cannot show html returned as jquery response in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to fetch members list based on a dropdown whose id is *cityname*. My idea is to fetch data from database and pass it to a php file where the desired html will be rendered and then bring this rendered html back to ajax call as *res*. Then place this response inside a div of the current web page. I did thid because I didnot want to write the HTML rendering code inside jquery.

I have an AJAX call as

```
$('#cityname').change(function(event) {
    $("#memberlist").empty();
    var ctname = $("select#cityname").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "User/getmemberlist",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {msname: ctname},
        success: function(res){
            if(res) {
                var len=res.length;
                $("#memberlist").empty();
                $("#memberlist").innerHTML(res);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('hitting');
            }
        },
        error: function(res, status, error) {
            var err = res.responseText;
            console.log(res.Message);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            alert('Please Refresh the page and Try Again.');
        }
    });
});
```

My Controller

```
public function getmemberlist()
{
    $data["members"]=$this->User_model->getmemberlist($this->input->post("msname"));
    $this->load->view('public/getmemberlist',$data);
    //echo json_encode($data['members']);
}
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
    if(isset($members) && !empty($members))
    {
        foreach($members as $e)
        {
            if(isset($e->pic) && !empty($e->pic))
            {
                echo '<div class="grid_4">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        <img src="'. base_url() .'assets/uploads/simg/'.$e->pic.'">
                    </div>
                    <article>
                        <h4>'.$e->name.'</h4>
                        <h5>'.$e->cityname.'</h5>
                    </article>
                  </div>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<div class="grid_4">
                    <div class="img_container">
                        <img src="'. base_url() .'assets/images/avataar.png" >
                    </div>
                    <article>
                        <h4>'.$e->name.'</h4>
                        <h5>'.$e->cityname.'</h5>
                    </article>
                  </div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

When I Inspect, the Network tab shows following response:

```
<div class="grid_4">
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="imageurl/4.jpg">
    </div>
    <article>
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <h5>2</h5>
    </article>
    </div><div class="grid_4">
        <div class="img_container">
            <img src="imageurl/3.jpg">
        </div>
    <article>
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <h5>2</h5>
    </article>
</div>
```

But Console gives following errors

```
undefined
Members:380 parsererror
Members:381 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.js:4)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:235)
    at Pc (jquery.js:4)
    at x (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:4)
```

I also tried

```
echo json_encode('<div class="grid_4">
<div class="img_container">
    <img src="'. base_url() .'assets/images/avataar.png" >
</div>
<article>
    <h4>'.$e->name.'</h4>
    <h5>'.$e->cityname.'</h5>
</article>
</div>');
```

and

```
$("#memberlist").innerHTML(JSON.parse(res));
```

> **UPDATE as per suggestions below**

Now I used json_encode inside my php code that renders html

```
echo json_encode('<div class="grid_4"><div class="img_container"><img src="'. base_url() .'assets/uploads/simg/'.$e->pic.'"></div><article><h4>'.$e->name.'</h4><h5>'.$e->cityname.'</h5></article></div>');
```

and updated ajax call code as below:

```
$("#memberlist").html(res);
```

Now the output in Network tab is:

```
"<div class=\"grid_4\"><div class=\"img_container\"><img src=\"imageurl\/4.jpg\"><\/div><article><h4>Neetu<\/h4><h5>2<\/h5><\/article><\/div>""<div class=\"grid_4\"><div class=\"img_container\"><img src=\"imageurl\/3.jpg\"><\/div><article><h4>Shobhit<\/h4><h5>2<\/h5><\/article><\/div>"
```

And the Console says:

```
undefined
Members:380 parsererror
Members:381 SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 194
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.js:4)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js:235)
    at Pc (jquery.js:4)
    at x (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:4)
```

> **NOTE: memberlist is the id of a div**

Comment: looks like your PHP is generating an HTML response, but the Javascript is expecting JSON

Comment: just  do $("#memberlist").html(res);

Comment: there is no function called innerHTML - that is native js and is set with an equals on the native dom object, if you use the jquery object use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and updated the new error log in the description of my problem. Please check and reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you messing with json when it is not required? Your output shows that you are receiving plain html. So, use your code with simple html request instead of json request. Update your code snippets as below:

> Ajax Request -- dataType: "html",
>
> Show response as: -- $("#memberlist").append(res);
>
> Send data from PHP file without json_encode

Things will then work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("#memberlist").innerHTML(res);
```

To:

```
$("#memberlist").html(res);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and updated the new error log in the description of my problem. Please check and reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass array response from controller
  echo json_encode($array);

Show html response in jquery
   $("#id").html(html_responseData);

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and updated the new error log in the description of my problem. Please check and reply. Thanks.